# Cleanup of Federated users in AzureB2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an AzureB2C tenant which is federated with an external provider google.

I have deleted the user in google and the user is no longer login able to the application.

Is there any standard clean up procedure in AzureB2C to cleanup the deleted users data ?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, if you don't delete the related external provider in the Azure B2C, you can only delete the user from the source provider like google provider delete user from google.